# ruamel.yam is not preserving all comments

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

Original YAML file is

```
toplevel:
  #comment1
  hello: gut
  #comment2
  howdy: gut #horizontalcomment
  #comment3
  #comment4
  gets: gut
  #comment5
```

In python, I did

```
yml = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_input_str)
exec("del yml['toplevel']['gets']")
output_str = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(yml)
```

output_str becomes

```
toplevel:
  #comment1
  hello: gut
  #comment2
  howdy: gut #horizontalcomment
  #comment5
```

and comment3 and comment4 disappear. Is this as-designed or is it a bug?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38252508/252648. Looks like the handling of comments are not fully done.

Comment: @mangoDrunk The intention of `ruamel.yaml`'s round-trip mode is to be able to load a YAML file (e.g. used for configuration), change some values and write the file back out without losing the comments. What the author, of the post you link to, tries to do lies beyond it designed purpose. There just happen to be some mechanisms in `ruamel.yaml` that make it more easy to achieve that goal, than starting from other Python packages in which comments are not fully done (i.e. every other Python package), including that the comments are not thrown away while reading.

Answer (score 0):

That is as designed. But is, as so much of ruamel.yaml, *underdocumented*, primarily as a result of laziness of the package author.

The comments are associated with the keys, not with some position relative to the beginning of a mapping. Because of the way the YAML is tokenized the comments are associated with a following key.
The result of this is that if there is no longer a key, the comment is still available, but no longer emitted.

That side effect of this is that if you do:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
toplevel:
  #comment1
  hello: gut
  #comment2
  howdy: gut #horizontalcomment
  #comment3
  #comment4
  gets: gut
  #comment5
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
del data['toplevel']['gets']
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

you get your `output_str`, and then if you follow that by:

```
data['toplevel']['gets'] = 42
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

you'll get:

```
toplevel:
  #comment1
  hello: gut
  #comment2
  howdy: gut #horizontalcomment
  #comment3
  #comment4
  gets: 42
  #comment5
```

so the comments "magically" reappear.

If you want to move the comments to the end of the nested mapping (with key 'toplevel'), you can do:

```
comment_tokens = data['toplevel'].ca.items['gets'][1]
del data['toplevel'].ca.items['gets']  # not strictly necessary
data['toplevel'].ca.end = comment_tokens
```

and you'll get:

```
toplevel:
  #comment1
  hello: gut
  #comment2
  howdy: gut #horizontalcomment
  #comment3
  #comment4
  #comment5
```

which is probably what you expected in the first place.

---

That leaves me wondering why you use `exec()` instead of directly using:

```
del yml['toplevel']['gets']
```